# How to create a subtle Gmail style animation

Tags: ios

I'm a big fan of the subtle animations that Google have implemented in their apps.

[Like this animation that is invoked when the user taps the "Write Mail" button.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aO-rBPxbd1U&feature=youtu.be)

I know this is a very broad question, but how is an animation like this produced?

Is the view itself rendered to a bitmap, and is the bitmap then animated?

I'm not an iOS developer, just a designer with an interest in UI animations.

Any hint on where to find tutorials or any other information on this subject is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might give you an idea http://srooltheknife.blogspot.ro/2012/03/custom-transition-animation-for-modal.html , although it will be a bit difficult if you don't have any iOS development experience.